# Write to XML using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xml

I have 2 NSMutableArray's. One is storing a string and the other is storing a set of NSMutableArray's. So the layout looks like this:

```
NSMutableArrayParent {
    NSMutableArrayChild {
        someString
    }
    NSMutableArrayChild {
        someString
    }
    NSMutableArrayChild {
        someString
    }
}
```

I wish to write this data into an XML file.

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956509/converting-nsdictionary-to-xml) but it does not specifically tell me HOW to write the XML file (in fact none of the questions here have).

I want the XML file to look something like this:

```
<parent name="someParentName">
      <child name="someChildName">  
             <data>someString</data>
      </child>        
</parent>
```

Now, like the answer in the linked question, I can append to a NSMutableString and get lines like this `<data>someString</data>` but how can I get the closing `child` and closing `parent` tag?

I went through [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) but it is using GDataXML over something native to Objective C.

Also, how can I actually write this XML to disk?

I'm using Objective C with a mac.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354769/nsmutable-array-to-xml-file

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kerberos. Somehow managed to miss this question.